What are the options to transfer a package from source machine to target machine over the network with only sudo user login via ssh?
adm package folder structure:
/opt/adm
├── bin
├── cli
├── dev
├── mod
├── pkg
└── sys

root@deb4 /opt/adm
# rwx

 To change permissions use this command syntax:
 $ sudo chmod <octal> <filename/foldername>

 USER = root  GROUPS = root

 PERMISSION |  OCTAL | OWNER          GROUP          NAME
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           .
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           ..
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           bin
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           cli
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           dev
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           mod
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           pkg
 drwxr-xr-x |   755  | root           root           sys

In this context adm package refers to all the files stored in the folder structure under /opt/adm/. On my development machine the adm package contains custom bash scripts in bin; it contains text files in cli; and package setup files in mod. The script rwx exists in the bin. Any user on the host machine can execute the rwx script to inspect octal permissions in the present working directory as shown above.
In general the adm package enables users on the host machine to run the bash scripts stored in bin from the command line; to read text files in cli; and to read text files in sys. The dev folder is for developing and testing new bash scripts prior to transfer to bin. The idea behind this package is to teach principles of bash setup, bash scripts, and Linux administration using bin to provide script resources and examples; cli to store notes; and sys to store system configuration notes.
I am not a power user or bash script expert. So the package and scripts might need improvement and feedback from the bash community to develop and evaluate it for teaching purposes. For now the package is private. I may publish it on Github someday.
I have two bash scripts in bin to transfer the whole adm package to another debian-based target machine. These scripts use rsync and tar respectively to show a dry run and then execute the transfer. The tar based script overwrites all existing files with the same names on the source and target. The rsync based script only updates files that have change or that don't already exist. I prefer the rsync. Both scripts work fine provided I have the root password login enabled via ssh for the target machine and I install rsync on the target if it does not exist already.
I have a machine that blocks root password login over ssh. I can only login as sudo user. What are my options to copy adm package to /opt/adm on the target machine with only sudo user login via ssh? Must I use keys to login as root? Or is there a way to transfer a tar file adm.tar then untar the file using sudo on the target machine?

What's wrong with copying the tar file to the sudo user's home directory and then using sudo to unpack it at the correct target location?

You have used adm package multiple times in this post. Does that mean adm as a command with package as an argument which uses the adm.tar file you're talking about?

@muru - Sorry if the notation is confusing. I will consider modifying the question for clarity. The term "adm package" refers to all the files under the directory /opt/adm/.  There is a script in the bin folder named adm.  This enables the User to list the top level directory tree: tree -L 1 /opt/adm.

You can copy your adm.tar file to the target system "sudo user"'s space with scp, then ssh in and unpsck/install.

You can, if you have passwordless ssh, and passwordless sudo on target.
scp adm.tar sudouser@target
scp doit    sudouser@target
ssh -L sudouser target sudo bash ./doit

I leave writing doit as an exercise for the student.

Besides the fact that i would recommend to just use non-root users for the whole big picture story (as you have no suid prgs?) simplifying it, your way may look like:
user@master#> sudo tar -C /opt/adm -cf - . \
| ssh user@targethost sudo tar -C /opt/adm -xf -

Untested, but i guess it should work.
Based on the comment the corrections needed for real life working:
A) provide the password for sudo on the target via stdin.
user@master#> ( printf 'sudo-password-at-target\n' ; sudo tar -C /opt/adm -cf - . ) \
| ssh user@targethost sudo -S tar -C /opt/adm -xf -

B) use sudo password-less with -n
user@master#> sudo tar -C /opt/adm -cf - . \
| ssh user@targethost sudo -n tar -C /opt/adm -xf -

How does it work?

you sudo into root on the master in order to create your tar
which you pipe over via ssh to the targethost
there you are sudo again into root and
untar the data of the pipeline.

;)
Outlooks beyond the solution:

if full tar becomes too expensive you may head for dar - http://dar.linux.free.fr/ (which support offline incremental updates, means you keep a catalog file from the target and the next incremental is based on that)
For rsync it also looks technically feasible but by far more complicated therefore i skip it, it would either go via the -e option faking the sudo part into a artificial ssh replacement or with the rsync-path option, boths ways are far way from being straight forward. So i would recommend to stay away from it.


This fails with the message: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified. The password for the sudo user on the target machine cannot be given.

thx for testing i updated the examples for two real life options.

I tried ssh -t option and sudo -n option. Still cannot execute task as sudo on remote machine.

so my test revealed that -t is not needed, sudo -n requires that you have sudo -l showing password less command execution for the tar cmd.
